# Why does this __getattr__ function not work?

Tags: python, getattr

I've got this little class I wrote to try playing with custom `__getattr__` methods, and every time I run it, I get an Attribute error:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs ={'attr':'hello'}
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.attrs:
            return self.attrs[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError

t = test()
print test.attr
```

The output is then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print test.attr
AttributeError: class test has no attribute 'attr'
```

What gives? I thought **getattr** was called before an attribute error was raised?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the class `test` **doesn't** have `attr` as an attribute, the instance `t` does:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs ={'attr':'hello'}
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.attrs:
            return self.attrs[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError

t = test()
print t.attr
```

Comment: It's happened to me, too, plenty of times.

Answer (score 4):

You have to query the attribute on the *instance* (`t`), not on the *class* (`test`):

```
>>> t = test()
>>> print t.attr
hello
```